# titles on html elements showing up under popover in safari extension

Tags: javascript, html, safari, safari-extension

I am currently in the process of porting a Chrome extension to Safari and have run into a weird bug. Some elements have a title attached to them to help explain what they do. These show up and work fine in the Chrome extension but on Safari they are actually appearing behind the popover window.

Here is an example: the one on top is Chrome the one on bottom is Safari. As you can see the title shows up fine in Chrome and says where the button will take you if clicked. On Safari... not so much.

[image: Chrome Extension]

[image]

The html is generated by javascipt as this is user content they have created but it looks the exact same on both platforms.

```
<a href="#" onclick="triggerSearchClick(&quot;12506&quot;)" class="attachment"  style="margin-top: -11px;" title="http://www.apple.com/startpage/">
<img src="img/stream_bookmark_icon.png" class="attachment_icon">
<span class="blast_link">Apple - Start</span></a>
```

You can clearly see that the title is there, so why is this not working in Safari? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Anyone out there have any idea on this at all?

Comment: I just copied what you have here, and it worked fine on my safari, can you confirm what version of safari you have that it's not working in?

Answer (score 0):

```
.attachment
{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}
```

Try this. Set z-index on the title greater than the window to define the stack order of the elements.